# Explanation of steric hindrance and existence of PI5

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability

I have come across a following line in my textbook:

> $\ce{PI5}$ does not exist due to steric hindrance.

I searched for the explanation of steric hindrance in Wikipedia but couldn't understand it. Can anyone explain steric hindrance in simpler language?

Wikipedia says:

> The existence of $\ce{PI5}$ has been claimed intermittently since the
>   early 1900s. The claim is disputed: "The pentaiodide does not exist
>   (except perhaps as $\ce{PI3\cdot I2}$, but certainly not as
>   $\ce{PI4+I-}$)".

What does this mean?

Comment: Interestingly, $\ce{PI4^+}$ does exist. So, the questions are 1)why phosphorous avoids forming more than four bonds (just like nitrogen) and 2) why $\ce{PI4^+}$ (and for that matter $\ce{PBr4^+}$) could be a rather strong oxidizer, strong enough to oxidize corresponding anion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that you can not fit five iodine atoms around a phosphorous atom.

Consider the [pentachloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_pentachloride) equivalent - this is already quite crowded. Since chlorine atoms have a smaller covalent radius than iodine, you can get five of them around the phosphorous. Of course, all this depends on the bond length of P-I and P-Cl and the size of the phosphorous atom.

Interestingly, there seems to be some suggestion of an uranium pentaiodide compound, for example [this PubChem compound](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/71308293). However, there are no references on that page, so presumably this has never been synthesised either?

In general, steric hindrance means geometric conformations of a molecule that are impossible (or difficult to achieve) due to clashes between groups and atoms within the molecule.

Comment: Uranium pentaiodide is also [hypothetical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_pentaiodide).

Comment: Quite possibly (the reference on that page is from 1968!) however, [there is a tantalum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_pentaiodide) compound that has been prepared (although I don't quite see how the shared edge X2Y10 structures are pentagonal bipyramidal, but whatever).

Comment: Sterical hindrance does NOT prevent formation of $\ce{CI4}$ (and similarly crouded $\ce{C6I6}$ for that matter), so it is not sufficient to say that $\ce{PI5}$ is too hindered to form

Comment: @permeakra Admittedly, I should not have assumed that steric hindrance is truly the main reason for preventing PI5. Are you saying that the carbon-iodine bonds in CI4 are shorter than phosporous-iodine bonds? Presumably CI4 is also tetrahedral, which PI5 could not be.

Comment: Hmmm. The bonds in CI4 are 212 pm whereas in PI3 they are 234 pm, so perhaps you are right.

Comment: @gilleain both $\ce{CI4}$ and $\ce{C6I6}$ have short I-I contacts well below $\ce{I}$ van-der-waals radius. In fact it seems that in $\ce{C6I6}$ there is enough overlapping to fully delocalize two positive charges over iodines, forming a rather stable $\ce{[C6I6]^{2+}}$

Comment: @permeakra Interesting! My point was only that **if** steric effects were the reason for the non-existence of PI5 **then** an explanation could be the VDW overlap of the iodines preventing them packing in the required geometry. Basically, I was taking the textbook at its word - always dangerous :)

Answer (score 4):

**$\ce{PI5}$ versus $\ce{CI4}$**

More is involved than steric hindrance  in preventing the formation of a $\ce{PI5}$ isomer with pentacoordinate phosphorus. There is a subtle antibonding interaction in this $\ce{PI5}$ isomer which does not occur in $\ce{CI4}$.

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/121199/17175) describes the hidden antibonding ligand-ligand interactions in the "nonbonding" ligand-based orbitals of "expanded octet" molecules such as $\ce{SF6}$. The ligand-ligand antibonding interaction is small enough to minimize its impact on $\ce{SF6}$. But $\ce{OF6}$, where central atom is smaller and the ligands are closer together, is less fortunate.

Similarly in $\ce{PI5}$ there is one ligand-based orbital that becomes antibonding with the ligand-ligand interactions. Occupation of that iodine-based orbital combined with its crowding around the smaller phosphorus atom thus poses a combined electronic-steric hindrance.

With $\ce{CI4}$, however, there is no such ligand-based "hidden antibonding" orbital because there is no formal octet expansion, and without this electronic factor $\ce{CI4}$ can hold together (at least if it's chilled) despite the unfavorable steric condition.*

*[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134588/17175) mentions the unusual deep red/purple color of this saturated compound. The relative weakness of the carbon-iodine bond, which moves normally ultraviolet electronic transitions into the visible range, explains the color.